# Redis, AOF file and Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, persistence, redis

Is there a way to save the AOF file on Amazon S3 instead of storing it locally?

This would avoid running out of space on disk for large datasets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can mount S3 as a drive letter (for example: [TntDrive](http://tntdrive.com/)) and set Redis to write to that drive, **but it's very wrong**; the latency will kill you. See http://redis.io/topics/latency under "*Latency due to AOF and disk I/O*".

Comment: What about mounting a huge EBS volume and store the file there? Do you think that may improve the I/O speed?

Comment: The latency remains - it's the Internet network between your Redis server and Amazon. Or else your Redis server is _ON_ Amazon right now? It's a completely different story.

Comment: Yes my configuration would consist in having Redis on Amazon, and then store the whole thing to S3/EBS.

Comment: If Redis goes to its storage within a LAN then it's OK - and you can do it as I described in the beginning of my answer.

Comment: Although even if both are placed in the same network, the latency is higher than it would be by just storing it on a local disk. You think this additional latency is negligible?

Comment: Yes, I think that in this case it's negligible. Redis forks its process to another one to do the writing, so I think it's pretty much OK. The reason I said in the beginning that the latency will kill you, is that if it's over the Internet, it might be so slow that even the forked process will be throttled waiting for the packets to go and get back (considering you fact that there are probably tens of thousands commands per second).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that, simply use `BGREWRITEAOF` to compress the size of the AOF periodically. Or work with dump files and not AOF files.